# can't install jetbrains youtrack on windows x64

Tags: windows, installation, jetbrains-ide, youtrack

We would like to try to use youtrack system in our development team, but we face with problems during installation youtrack. During installation installer is hagning on line "Create folder: D:\Program Files\YouTrack\logs". We see that problem on different machines and for that reason can't install YouTrack. What should be the reason of that problem and how to fix that?
Thank you,

Comment: Have you tried to run an installer "as administrator"?

Answer (score 1):

Try read the [Installation Instructions](http://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/download/installation_instructions_exe.html) from **JetBrains** or contact their [Support](http://www.jetbrains.com/support/youtrack/)

**Update:** i see you already did [ http://forum.jetbrains.com/thread/YouTrack-1563 ]